# Whatis command (shell builtin vs executable programs)

Tags: shell, command-line, command, echo, shell-builtin

I know that whatis command is used to output a brief description about an executable program (Command).

So both

```
whatis cd

whatis type
```

Will print: nothing appropriate (Because from my understanding they are both shell builtins). However how come, it works for

```
whatis echo
```

even though, echo is a shell builtin, is there any explanation for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for echo because is both a shell builtin *and* a command. By default, the builtin is used.

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type -P echo # ignores builtins
/bin/echo
$ echo foo # builtin
foo
$ /bin/echo foo # external command
foo
```

Comment: `type` does not implement options and `command echo` executes the builtin command.

Comment: @schily I removed the `command` example. What do you mean `type` does not implement options? POSIX doesn't require it to support options, but it does in `bash`, and `zsh`. It exists in the answer for demonstration.

Comment: bash and zsh are not typical POSIX shells and never have been tested for POSIX compliance. POSIX does not mention options and the Bourne Shell and ksh88 do not implement options. For this reason, it does not help to mention vendor specific options.